# Pandas apply not expanding with string split

Tags: pandas

I am trying to use apply to split multiple columns of delimited strings into 4 columns each on version `0.25.3`

By using `.apply` with `.str.split` I get back columns of lists like so

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['9;1;8;11', '2;10;8;11', '9;4;7;10'], 'B':['0;1;6;2', '2;6;6;3', '2;1;1;2']})
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';'), axis=1)
```

output :

```
                A             B
0   [9, 1, 8, 11]  [0, 1, 6, 2]
1  [2, 10, 8, 11]  [2, 6, 6, 3]
2   [9, 4, 7, 10]  [2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Which leads me to believe that simply adding `result_type='expand'` should expand the lists into separate columns as the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) explains,

> Passing result_type='expand' will expand list-like results to columns of a Dataframe

However,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';'), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

returns the exact same result:

```
                A             B
0   [9, 1, 8, 11]  [0, 1, 6, 2]
1  [2, 10, 8, 11]  [2, 6, 6, 3]
2   [9, 4, 7, 10]  [2, 1, 1, 2]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split` is a function for series, if we do like use it for dataframe we can

```
df=pd.concat([df[x].str.split(';',expand=True) for x in df.columns],axis=1)
Out[37]: 
   0   1  2   3  0  1  2  3
0  9   1  8  11  0  1  6  2
1  2  10  8  11  2  6  6  3
2  9   4  7  10  2  1  1  2
```